# Qt QMediaPlayer - QThread::start: Failed to create thread

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer

I develop an application which the user can play multiple sounds at the same time. For this I use `QMediaPlayer` in conjunction with a matrix to hold each sound separately. The code is simple, for each sound I use a code like this:

```
media = new QMediaPlayer();
media->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo("sound.mp3").absoluteFilePath()));
media->play();
```

Everything is ok. But around playing the sound 115-125 (simultaneous sounds), the new sounds emit signal `error(QMediaPlayer::ResourceError)` with error code: `QMediaPlayer::ResourceError - A media resource couldn't be resolved`. Before emit error signal, it print on output this message: `DirectShowPlayerService::doPlay: Unresolved error code 0x80004005 ()`

This is not a problem, because I delete those sounds as soon as I detect this error.
The problem appears right after a couple of `QMediaPlayer::ResourceError`.
If I create a new sound, an error message appear on output window: `QThread::start: Failed to create thread.`
This error appear just after creating a new `QMediaPlayer` instance:

```
qDebug() << "before media = new QMediaPlayer(); (FILE)";
media = new QMediaPlayer();
qDebug() << "after media = new QMediaPlayer(); (FILE)" << media->error
```

The output:

```
before media = new QMediaPlayer(); (FILE)
QThread::start: Failed to create thread
after media = new QMediaPlayer(); (FILE) QMediaPlayer::NoError
```

This last kind of `QMediaPlayer` instance emit no error. More than that, the state is `QMediaPlayer::PlayingState`. But if I try to delete it `delete(media)` or to set the media to a null `QMediaContent` `media->setMedia(QMediaContent())` to make the player to discard all information relating to the current media source, the application freezes.
Those two opperations works fine on he others sounds.
If I don't delete this kind of `QMediaPlayer`, I end to have no room for sounds. Somehow `QMediaPlayer` has a limited number of instances and every `QMediaPlayer` that I cannot delete anymore fill this number and let no room for new instances of `QMediaPlayer`.

The question is: how I can avoid this issue? If I limit the number of simultaneous sounds, what is the correct number of `QMediaPlayer` instances? If I set a limit, this limit can be to high for other machines. Or how to properly detect this malformed QMediaPlayer and properly delete it?

Also, if I wait for first `QMediaPlayer::ResourceError` signal to limit the number of sounds, this is sometimes too late, because the error signal is emitted a bit later and sometimes the application already create a malformed `QMediaPlayer` that I cannot delete anymore and this prevent the process to close.